# Equal frequency and equal width binning in R

Tags: r

Given a dataset, I want to partition it into 4 bins using both equal frequency binning and equal width binning as described [here](http://www.saedsayad.com/unsupervised_binning.htm), But I want to use R language.

Dataset:

```
0, 4, 12, 16, 16, 18, 24, 26, 28
```

I have tried to write a little code for equal width binning but it just produces a histogram.

```
bins<-4;
minimumVal<-min(dataset)
maximumVal<-max(dataset)
width=(maximumVal-minimumVal)/bins;
edges = minimumVal:width:maximumVal;
hist(dataset, breaks = "Sturges", freq = TRUE, xlim = range(edges))
```

I am new to R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For equal width binning, I suggest using the `classInt` package:

```
dataset <- c(0, 4, 12, 16, 16, 18, 24, 26, 28)

library(classInt)
classIntervals(dataset, 4)
x <- classIntervals(dataset, 4, style = 'equal')
```

To use the breaks, you can check `x$brks`.

As for equal frequency binning, you could use the same package, with option `style = 'quantile'`:

```
classIntervals(dataset, 4, style = 'quantile')
```

It doesn't separate in exactly equal sized bins because of repeated values in `dataset` (16) and because the dataset simply can't be split exactly in 4 bins with strictly the same number of elements because it has 9 elements. I don't know if this is an issue, because in the reference provided, it says that

> "... each group contains *approximately* same number of values."

As you didn't explicit the exact method you are looking for, I suggest referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741495/1930564) for another method, in your example it would be:

```
library(Hmisc)
table(cut2(dataset, m = length(dataset)/4))
```

Also, the other posts in the link suggested above provide other alternatives and some relevant discussion about these methods.

Comment: classIntervals work perfectly for both types of binning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for `equal-width-binning`:

```
set.seed(1)
dataset <- runif(100, 0, 10) # some random data
bins<-4
minimumVal<-min(dataset)
maximumVal<-max(dataset)
width=(maximumVal-minimumVal)/bins;
cut(dataset, breaks=seq(minimumVal, maximumVal, width))

#[1] (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92]  (5.03,7.47]  (5.03,7.47]  (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58]
#[13] (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (5.03,7.47]  (0.134,2.58]
#[25] (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  <NA>         (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03]  (0.134,2.58] (7.47,9.92]  (5.03,7.47] 
#[37] (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (5.03,7.47]  (7.47,9.92]  (5.03,7.47]  (5.03,7.47]  (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (2.58,5.03] 
#[49] (5.03,7.47]  (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03] 
#[61] (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (0.134,2.58] (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92] 
#[73] (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92]  (2.58,5.03]  (5.03,7.47]  (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03] 
#[85] (7.47,9.92]  (0.134,2.58] (5.03,7.47]  (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (0.134,2.58] (5.03,7.47]  (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92]  (7.47,9.92] 
#[97] (2.58,5.03]  (2.58,5.03]  (7.47,9.92]  (5.03,7.47] 
#Levels: (0.134,2.58] (2.58,5.03] (5.03,7.47] (7.47,9.92]

#plot frequencies in the bins
barplot(table(cut(dataset, breaks=seq(minimumVal, maximumVal, width))))
```

[image]