# removing noises with equal depth binning in R by replacing each bins with its mean or median

Tags: r, noise, smoothing

For example I have a vector like this :

```
a <- c(4, 8, 9, 15, 21, 21, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 34)
```

and I want to do this:

Step 1:

Partition into equal-frequency (equi-depth)

Bins:

- Bin 1: 4, 8, 9, 15
- Bin 2: 21, 21, 24, 25
- Bin 3: 26, 28, 29, 34

Step2:

Smoothing by bin means:

- Bin 1: 9, 9, 9, 9
- Bin 2: 23, 23, 23, 23
- Bin 3: 29, 29, 29, 29

Output :

```
9,9,9,9,23,23,23,23,29,29,29,29
```

Comment: Why is it divided into 3 bins of 4 each and not 4 bins of 3 each or 6 bins of 2 each ? Do you always want 4 bins?

Comment: First part of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037740/equal-frequency-and-equal-width-binning-in-r. After that, it's a simple replacing of values...

Comment: @Ronak It is not my problem right now. you imagine you can set number of bins manually by a simple parameter

Comment: @Wimpel your link is not related to this question. I can easly handle part1 with just using split function. the hard part is step2. how can I replace automaticly each bins with it mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create groups by dividing `length` of `a` in equal number of bins and use `ave` to calculate rounded `mean` in each group.

```
no_of_bins <- 4
round(ave(a, rep(1:length(a), each = no_of_bins, length.out = length(a))))
#[1]  9  9  9  9 23 23 23 23 29 29 29 29
```

PS -

- `ave` has default function as `mean` so it has not been explicitly applied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (take *Orange$age* predefined R variable as your input, 10 is the bin size)

```
v=split(Orange$age, ceiling(seq_along(Orange$age)/10))
lapply(v, function(item){rep(mean(item), length(item))})
```